# non-oop way to display records or fields - mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been using mysql and it did what I want, but as my project is getting larger, I decided to opt for mysqli.

I looked at the tutorial at [enter link description here](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17) which was really straight forward up until the point where I want to display some data

stored procedure (connect.php)

```
<?php

function db_connect() {

    // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $con;

    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($con)) {
         // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if( $con === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return  $con;
}

function db_query($query) {
    // Connect to the database
     $con = db_connect();


    // Query the database
    $result = mysqli_query( $con,$query);

    return $result;
}

function db_error() {
     $con = db_connect();

        return mysqli_error($con);
}

function db_select($query) {
    $rows = array();
    $result = db_query($query);

    // If query failed, return `false`
    if($result === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // If query was successful, retrieve all the rows into an array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
function db_quote($value) {
     $con = db_connect();

        return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value) . "'";
}
?>
```

php/html

```
<div class="grid_4">
        <div class="left-1">
            <h2 class="top-1 p3">Find a property</h2>
            <form id="form-1" method="post" class="form-1 bot-1" action="prop_result.php">
                <div class="select-1">
                    <label>Select Area</label>
                    <select name="field4" id="field4" >
    <?php



$rows = db_select("SELECT id,city_id,area FROM area");
    if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();

    }else
    {
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<option value=""><?php $rows['
area'];?></option>

<?php 
}}

?>

                    </select>   
                </div>
```

What I don't understand is how to use the stored procedure in a while loop so it will output the data in the fields ID and Area so my select box and any other input can be properly populated based on the query

current

I've tried different ways :

```
<?php



$rows = db_select("SELECT id,city_id,area FROM area");
    if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();

        }
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<option value=""><?php $rows['
area'];?></option>

<?php 
}

?>
```

and

```
$rows = db_select("SELECT id,city_id,area FROM area");
    if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();

        }
{
?>
<option value=""><?php $rows['
area'];?></option>

<?php 
}

?>
```

and

```
 <?php



$rows = db_select("SELECT area_id from property");
    if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();

    }

{
echo "<option value='".$rows['id']."'>".$rows[$col4]."</option>";
}
    ?>
```

None of these output any data. Echoing $rows gives no data. I don't know what the logic is for using the stored procedure to display the output.

Any help would be appreciated, if any other information is required to assist in resolving this issue, please let me know.

Comment: I am guessing that  when you echo $rows you get Array()?
Trying doing a print_r($rows) and see what you get.

Comment: Also...because db_query() returns the already parsed array you don't need to use mysqli_fetch_assoc().
This is where a foreach() loop might help out.

Comment: i get this Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [type] => Apartment ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [type] => Land ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [type] => Villa ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siniseus way works but its too much code for a simple task. I did work with it to finally come to this

```
<select name="field4" id="field4" >

<?php       
$rows = db_select("SELECT id, city_id,area FROM area");
foreach($rows as $row){
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['area']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Simple, clean and really straight forward without too many variables.

$rows = db_select ("Select Query")foreach($rows as $row){
do this
}

Answer (score 1):

Awesome to hear that the data is returning. Try this out for size...

```
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if($k == 'id'){
           $newID = $v;
        }
        if($k == 'type'){
           $newType = $v
        }
    }
    echo "<option value='".$newID."'>".$newType."</option>";
}
```

with this you should be able to make it work for you liking.

Edit: Didnt see the additional arrays until later...the nested loop should suite you better.

Comment: seems like its working . but now how to use it  so i can easily list only area. i don't suppose i need to use that code for each iteration. => Set 0 : id = 3
type = Apartment
Set 1 : id = 2
type = Land
Set 2 : id = 1
type = Villa

Comment: I altered the code above to what you are looking for.

Comment: added a little more...sorry for the bug.

Comment: ok its working to what i want but it seems to be a lot of code which i can't follow. isn't there any way without declaring $key. like in a mysql i would just do this -> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['area]."</option>";
}

Comment: because of your function db_select the mysqli_fetch_assoc is already being executed there. This function then returns the array $rows filled with all the data from the mysqli_fetch_assoc execution. 

Using a foreach loop is the easiest way to iterate through each element of the array.

Comment: i've already declared the db_select function but didn't know how to use it in the correct way. your $key and v code works, but i think it will be very complicated to use . is there anyway i can use the stored procedure and not set $key just fetch the results.

Comment: Last comment.....Based on your previous code I have updated it to work with you displaying the <option> tag with the filled data.

Please +1 this.

Comment: i appreciate all this. so for each select i need to type in  $rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM $table4 ");
      
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if($k == 'area'){
           echo "ID = " . $v . "<br />";
    }
}
}
and change the variables as required?....seems to be defeating the purpose of stored procedure. anyway. i will see if there are any other answers